# Converting an image into a vector of pixels

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to convert an image into an array of pixels.
Here is my current code.

```
im = Image.open("beeleg.png")
pixels = im.load()
im.getdata() # doesn't work
print(pixels # doesn't work
```

Ideally, my end goal is to convert the image into a vector of just pixels, so for instance if I have an image of dimensions `100x100`, then I want a vector of dimensions `1x10000`, where each value is between [0, 255]. Then, divide each of the values in the array by `256` and add a bias of `1` in the front of the vector. However, I am not able to proceed with all this without being able to obtain an array. How to proceed?

Comment: use [`scipy.ndimage.imread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html#scipy.ndimage.imread) to read into a numpy array (which can then be reshaped at will). Use mode `'L'` for an 8 bit grayscale image

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy's `ndimage` library is generally the go-to library for working with pixels as data (arrays). You can load an image from file (most common formats supported) using `scipy.ndimage.imread` into a numpy array which can be easily reshaped and mathematically operated on. The `mode` keyword can be used to specify a colorspace transformation upon load (convert an RGB image to black and white). In your case you asked for single color pixels from 0-255 (8bit grayscale) so you would use `mode='L'`. See [The Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html#scipy.ndimage.imread) for usage / more useful functions.

Comment: I also have a small side question. This image gives me a 2d array. However, I would like to have a one-hot encoding (1d vector) of the image. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: @Christian you should now have a numpy array of pixel values. assuming `img = imread(stuff)` you could call `length = np.prod(img.shape); img = img.reshape(length)`. Alternatively you could use the ndarray's [`flatiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatiter.html) attribute, which gives you a memory view of the array as if it were flat without actually shifting the memory around. The latter being the better approach in general, it may not be treated as a regular array by some functions resulting in incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If use `OpenCV`, `gray=cv2.imread(image,0)` will return a grayscale image with `n rows` x `m cols` single channel numpy array. `rows, cols = gray.shape` will return the height and width of the image.